# how to increase an int number using alarm manager

Tags: android

I want to write an app that increase an int number every fifteen minute using alarm manager and saves new value in shared preferences and then showing value in text view. I am totally new and tried many things but in vain.please be kind if you find some thing that is not well and explain me. thank you.
here is code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
AlarmManager am;

    int d=3;
    TextView tv;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ed);

        }

    public void time(Context context,Intent intent){
        am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent;
        Intent intnt = new Intent(context, MyAlarm.class);
        // Set the alarm to start at approximately 2:00 p.m.
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
d++;
// With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
// constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, alarmIntent);
    }
    public void shared(){
        sp = (SharedPreferences) getSharedPreferences("sha", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putInt("as", d);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public void show(int i){
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ed);
        int q=sp.getInt("as",d);
        tv.setText(q);

    }
}
```

and service is;

```
public class MyAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //the method will be fired when the alarm is triggerred
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of the increment could be done in the `MyAlarm` class, in the `onReceive` method, when you receive the alarm, this is the place you should be responding to.

```
public class MyAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //the method will be fired when the alarm is triggerred
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences sp = (SharedPreferences) getSharedPreferences("sha", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int d = sp.getInt("as", 0);// get the previous value
        d = d + 1;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putInt("as", d);
        editor.commit();// finally, save it
    }

}
```

Your activity can then be cleaned up to look something similar to this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AlarmManager am;

    int d=3;// do you really need this?
    TextView tv;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ed);
        int q=sp.getInt("as",0);// this should return an integer if available, otherwise 0
        tv.setText(String.format("%d", q));// format the integer as a String
        am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent;
        Intent intnt = new Intent(this, MyAlarm.class);// I replaced context with `this` because AppCompatActivity and any Activity is a Context in Android applications
        // Set the alarm to start at approximately 2:00 p.m.
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intnt, 0);
        d++;// you never used this value here, is it really needed?
// With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
// constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, alarmIntent);
    }


/* Function is not used in the flow
        public void shared(){
            sp = (SharedPreferences) getSharedPreferences("sha", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putInt("as", d);
            editor.commit();
        }*/
/* Function could be inlined in the onCreate method
        public void show(int i){
            tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ed);
            int q=sp.getInt("as",d);
            tv.setText(q);

        }*/
    }
```

If you are having problems with this, I think you should find the docs and read about Activity life cycles, AlarmManager and you can find some good books on Android development online. Video tutorials are also good for some people, but I suggest you read books and network with as many other developers as you meet. There's a future ahead!

Comment: one more question. you asked me is there really neaded to use int d=3; when I removed it. unresolved d error is showing. also in alarmintent Context is underlined and studio saying expression expected.

Comment: My answer has typos so I'm fixing them so your issues are resolved in some way. You should probably read more books on programming in general (not Android programming only, but real programming, you can review C++ or Java).